# Are TIE fighters significantly better than X-Wing fighters?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In The Force Awakens, Poe's X-Wing on Jakku is disabled, then destroyed by regular hand held blaster fire, courtesy of FN-2187's First Order storm trooper squad.

Later, when FN-2187 and Poe are attempting to escape in an TIE fighter, it takes multiple hits from what seems like the same blasters, yet it doesn't even look damaged. The storm troopers were attempting to set up a larger blaster cannon emplacement to take it down, before the cannon was taken out by the TIE fighters blasts.

Does this mean the TIE fighters are significantly better than the X-Wings? Or did I miss something? Or is this just a goof?

Comment: I think X-Wings are only better when the shields are up. Tie Fighters have no shield and therefore maybe have a thicker hull.

Comment: Doesn't matter, all you need is to be strong with the force!

Comment: Star Wars was never as strong as Star Trek in terms of scientific research.  As such, I think you're not really supposed to dissect the science unless you want to see the flaws.  Just accept that Poe needed to be shot down on Jakku and needed to escape from the Star Destroyer.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike previous generations of TIE fighters, the [Special Forces TIE/sf](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE/sf_space_superiority_fighter) actually comes equipped with a compact shield generator.

[image]

<sub><sup>**image from [Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Incredible Cross-sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_Incredible_Cross-Sections)**</sup></sub>

It would appear that Poe Dameron was able to activate this shield before the ship was hit with the blaster fire from the bay. It's mentioned slightly later on in the film's [Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)) (when they take out the Star Destroyer's lasers) that the shields are active.

> The whole gun emplacement erupted in a rapidly shrinking fireball.
>   Debris spun around them as Poe took them through the devastation, the
>   fighter’s shields warding off whatever he could not directly avoid.

By comparison, there's no indication that Poe had activated the X-Wing's shields. He was trying to avoid being detected by scanners until he was in a position to attempt a quick takeoff. That presumably would include not activating systems with large electromagnetic signatures that could be tracked,  such as the shields and main weapons.

> The ship that was parked some distance from the village was well
>   hidden beneath a high rock outcropping. That wouldn’t shield the
>   X-wing from sophisticated search gear, Poe knew. He needed to exit the
>   atmosphere, and fast.